# How to automate calculate in salesforce using CPQ API QuoteCalculator

Tags: cpq

Need to automate the Calculate button background process in salesforce.

Referred the documentation - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.214.0.cpq_api_dev.meta/cpq_api_dev/cpq_quote_api_calculate_final.htm

But Quote Calculator is not global class. Any way around ?

Answer (score 0):

Needhi, If I understand the question are you asking for a way to have the calculation sequence (that gets triggered when you click Calculate) to be triggered without the user actually clicking it?

If this is accurate, one way you can try is (this is theoretical but please test it ):

Step 1 : Create a custom field number,text, checkbox etc
Step 2 : Add this field to Quote's "calculating Fields" Field set
Step 3 : Use Flow or manual updation on the custom fields so that this triggers the calculation sequence without you manually clicking Calculate again

Note: In general updating any field on the Calculating Fields field set triggers a recalculation.So what we are trying to achieve here is to update this custom field that will be a part of the field set to prompt the system to calculate again.